# Does this function $ h $ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

If we have a function $ f $ from the interval [-1,1] into the real numbers  and $ f(x)=0 $ when $ x $ is greater than or equal to -1 and less than or equal to 0 and $ f(x)= 1 $ for $ x $ greater than 0 and less than or equal to 1, does there exist another function $ h $ going from [-1,1] to the real numbers such that $h'(x)=f(x) $?

Comment: The answer is no; one can prove that derivatives, even when they are not continuous, satisfy the intermediate value property (that is, the conclusion of the intermediate value theorem).

Comment: @Axoren I don't see the problem; it seems to be $f(x)=0$ if $x \in [-1,0]$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x \in (0,1]$.

Comment: @Ian My mistake, I could have sworn it said greater than or equal to 0 on the second bound. The question could use some reformatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h(x) = 0$ if $-1 \leq x \leq 0$

$h(x) = x$ if $0 < x \leq 1$ should do it.